# Recursion vs classic algorithm complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Recursive Functions are efficient in many cases and used widely in implementing algorithms like :

- Searching Algorithms -> Binary Search
- Sorting Algorithms -> Merge Sort

Time complexity cost of recursive function O(logn) or O(nlogn) is low if we compare it with traditional algorithms which easy to analyze by our way of thinking.

But if we discuses the complexity of writing the recursive functions for more complex tasks it's difficult for the logic of our mind to analyze how it works perfectly.

The question here does that means the pattern of writing a complex function to behave like how computer work more efficient than actually how our mind think of how computer work?!

[image]

Comment: Every program expressed recursively can also be expressed iteratively. Tail call optimization is not supported in Python so it doesn't factor in here. Hence the best algorithm will not depend on that choice, only on its specific implementation. Highly optimized code tends to be hard to understand but your question is somewhat unclear as it's currently stated.

Comment: 'Highly optimized code tends to be hard to understand' here you mention the point highly optimized algorithm which use recursion in its implementation as example for doing specific complex task does that actually means it's better because we implement it in a way more familiar of how computer works than the way how our mind think ?!

Comment: Computers and minds work very differently so yes, if you strongly optimize for one of them, odds are that you will sacrifice performance on the other. So you need to compromise between the two, preferring readability if possible and only choosing computational performance if strictly necessary.

Comment: Very explicit and valuable reply. I agree with you, if you can write your reply as answer to contribute to the question.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the nuance of the question, but it seems like you think that recursive functions are harder to write and analyze but more efficient than iterative ones. I guess it's partly subjective, but I think this is almost completely backwards. In particular, there's very few optimized use-cases for recursion, and it's mostly when the algorithm is naturally recursive and cost of a function call is small compared to the other work being done. Mergesort for example.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes in some cases recursive function more efficient than classic iterative function as you mention but as I said to Jan that writing recursive function for some specific complex tasks maybe hard to debug perfectly as we expect if we compare it of how our mind think when writing algorithm and analyzing it.

Comment: "Recursive Functions are very efficient" that isn't a sound generalization. Indeed, often, unless the language supports tail-call optimization, recursive algorithms will be *less efficient* than the equivalent iterative algorithm that takes advantage of looping constructs because the recursion requires memory for the call stack.

Comment: @Oghli name those cases. You keep making that claim, but as everyone has pointed out, every recursive algorithm can be re-written into an iterative one.

Comment: I don't understand the question unless it's asking something tautological: "is optimizing for how a computer works better than optimizing for how a computer doesn't work?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mention in the question some cases like binary search, merge sort and quick sort.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think you understand my point well does implementing the algorithm as our mind way of thinking efficient as how actually computer work in low level representation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when converting recursive algorithm to a non-recursive one, the logic is much more complex and doing so requires the use of a stack.
I am talking about classic iterative algorithms as PaulHankin said.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for stackoverflow -- because "how a mind thinks a computer works" is subjective, and the scope of all algorithms that may or may not be naturally recursive is too broad. It's clear that writing optimized code is very difficult in general, and that often large efficiency gains are available (typically multiples of times faster even without changing algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Every program expressed recursively can also be expressed iteratively. Tail call optimization is not supported in Python so it doesn't factor in here. Hence the best algorithm will not depend on that choice, only on its specific implementation.

Highly optimized code tends to be hard to understand because computers and minds work very differently. So if you strongly optimize for one of them, odds are that you will sacrifice performance on the other. You need to compromise between the two, preferring readability if possible and only choosing computational performance if strictly necessary.

Comment: @Oghli why do you want to delete the question? Other people may have a similar idea/issue and there is some valuable advice in the comments.